# I want to get product id after order is paced using observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

**events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="vendor_modulename_observer_customorder" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Customorder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Customorder.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

class Customorder implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {

   $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');
  }
}
```

> above code its not working could any one suggest what is the mistake. I have tried with *"checkout_onepage_controller_success_action"* but there is not log file created

***How to get order id after place order ?***

Comment: Vendor\ModuleName Is supposed to be the Vendor and ModuleName of your Module. Copying and pasting code without modification is unlikely to work.

Comment: @NetStorm  I have tried with different name also but result is same

Comment: @Tanmay before check code please run upgrade command. please check and update.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This way**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="order_id_get" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\Customorder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Customorder.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

class Customorder  implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        echo $orderId;
        exit();
    }
}
```

> **You can also use this event.**

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="order_id_get_event" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\Customorder" />
</event>
```

> You can also use logger code to check order id.

Answer (score 0):

you can do below way

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

class Customorder  implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
           echo $item->getProductId();
        }
    }
}
```